# does python 3.9 supports skype4py

Tags: python

I am trying to import skype4py to python 3.9, but it is throwing the below error. Please help with this.

Command errored out with exit status 1:

> ```
> python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement skype4py (from versions: 1.0.32.1, 1.0.33, 1.0.34, 1.0.35)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for skype4py
> ```

Answer (score 3):

That's not the right question.  The question is "does skype4py support Python 3.9?"

A quick look at the documentation (https://pypi.org/project/Skype4Py/) shows that it does not support Python 3 at all.  It was last updated in 2013.

Comment: Just to emphasize, 2013 is the medieval era as far as technology is concerned. Computers move fast and technology marches on, so while 2013 was only nine years ago, that may as well be an eternity when it comes to the life cycle of software libraries.

Comment: There is a [`python3-beta`](https://github.com/Skype4Py/Skype4Py/tree/python3-beta) branch, but that also does not appear to be in active development.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out on how the question should be structured.